# is_Prime() function on PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, primes

I tried to make an **is_Prime()** function in PHP. What do you think about this code?

```
<?php
function is_Prime($x)
{
  if($x <= 1)
  {
    echo $x. " is not a prime number.</br>";
    return false;
  }
  $data = array();
  for ($i=1;$i<=$x;$i++) 
  { 
    if(is_integer($x/$i))
    {
        array_push($data, ($x/$i));
    }
  }
  if(count($data)>2)
  {
    echo $x." is not a prime number</br>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo $x. " is a prime number</br>";
  }
}
?>
```

How to use?

```
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
  is_Prime($i);
}
```

Comment: Kind of strange naming of your function. Either use `isPrime()` or `is_prime()`, mixing camelCase and snake_case looks odd

Comment: A related approach is the [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 3):

All primes end in either 1, 3, 7, or 9.  You could do a check up front to make sure the number satisfies that requirement.

Second, a number is prime if it has no prime factors besides itself and 1.  Therefore you should start you checking loop at 3, not at 1.  Since you only need to check against primes, you could start the loop at 3, increment it by 10, and check `$x/$i`, `$x/($i+4)`, `$x/($i+6)`, and `$x/($i+8)`.  That would be 4 divide operations instead of the 10 you are presently doing.

Third, you only have to check possible factors up to the square root of the number you are checking, so figure out the `sqrt($x)` and make that the end of the loop.  You are also putting all the factors you find into an array, which is not necessary if you are simply trying to see if the number is prime.

Comment: To achieve the second point, there is a trick at end of this [answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/104535/78136). Start with `$i=5` and `$add=2`. Then when incrementing `$i` you do `$i += $add` and `$add = 6 - $add`. This will alternate the increment of `$i` between 2 and 4, which skips all numbers divisible by 2, 3, and 6.  Changing the increment, would allow you to keep the division test as is, as you skip the unneccessary `$i` .

Comment: 2 is prime, so the first point might need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version of your code and an explanation of what I did and why.

```
<?php

function isPrime($number)
{
    if ($number <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    $isPrime = true;
    for ($i = 2; $i < $number ; $i++) {
        if (is_integer($number / $i)) {
            $isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $isPrime;
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo $i;
    echo isPrime($i) ? " is a prime number" : " isn't a prime number";
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

1. Use four spaces for indentation as per [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). This will make your code more readable.
2. Stick to camelCase for your function name as per [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/). This will make your code more readable.
3. Make your function return true or false so you can use your code in multiple places without having to change what it outputs. This will make your code reusable.
4. Make your function properties more descriptive. This will make your code more readable.
5. Make your for loop start at two as we have establish at the top of the function that the number isn't equal to one or less. This will increase performance of your code.
6. Make your loop stop at one number before the number in question as we know it will be divisible by itself. This will increase performance of your code.
7. Make your loop exit as soon as it hits an integer. We have already excluded the number itself and the number one so we can be sure it isn't a prime number. This will increase performance of your code.

Comment: The `$isPrime` can be dropped, just return true or false.  And related to (6) the loop should be terminated at around  `sqrt(n) ` not `n-1`, that would half the execution time...

Comment: @holroy Thanks for the critique! Point taken regarding `$isPrime`, what's the reason behind stopping at the square root of the number?

Comment: You've already compared the other side. Take 21  where `sqrt(21)<5`, when you've tested 3, there is no need to test for 7...